# Read/Write/Find/Replace huge csv file

Tags: file, csv, replace, cut-and-paste

I have a huge (4,5 GB) csv file.. I need to perform basic cut and paste, replace operations for some columns.. the data is pretty well organized.. the only problem is I cannot play with it with Excel because of the size (2000 rows, 550000 columns).

here is some part of the data:

```
ID,Affection,Sex,DRB1_1,DRB1_2,SENum,SEStatus,AntiCCP,RFUW,rs3094315,rs12562034,rs3934834,rs9442372,rs3737728

D0024949,0,F,0101,0401,SS,yes,?,?,A_A,A_A,G_G,G_G
D0024302,0,F,0101,7,SN,yes,?,?,A_A,G_G,A_G,?_?
D0023151,0,F,0101,11,SN,yes,?,?,A_A,G_G,G_G,G_G
```

I need to remove 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th columns;
I need to find every _ character from column 10 onwards and replace it with a space ( ) character;
I need to replace every ? with zero (0);
I need to replace every comma with a tab;
I need to remove first row (that has column names;
I need to replace every 0 with 1, every 1 with 2 and every ? with 0 in 2nd column;
I need to replace F with 2, M with 1 and ? with 0 in 3rd column;

so that in the resulting file the output reads:

```
D0024949 1 2 A A A A G G G G

D0024302 1 2 A A G G A G 0 0

D0023151 1 2 A A G G G G G G
```

(both input and output should read one line per row, ne extra blank row)
Is there a memory efficient way of doing that with java(and I need a code to do that) or a usable tool for playing with this large data so that I can easily apply Excel functionality..

Comment: you could consider tools like [sed and awk](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/sedawk.html)

Comment: Why not simply read a row of data, parse as comma delimited, perform desired actions, write the new comma delimited line to a new file, go back to step 1.  If your data is clean then you could  simply split the line on the comma or parse with basic csv rules or even a regex might work.  I don't see what's so difficult?

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:
- Knowledge of Regular Expressions (aka Regex, Regexes)
- [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/)